# Why could form 25 (SEC) has effective date on the next day?

Tags: sec, edgar

I try to understand delisting procedure. Companies fill the form 25 (25-NSE) if they want to delist. However the effective date of the delisting is 10 days after the publication of the form. (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sec-form-25.asp)

At the same time NASDAQ publishes list of issues that are pending suspension or delisting (https://listingcenter.nasdaq.com/IssuersPendingSuspensionDelisting.aspx) where there are some tickers that have effective date 1 day after the Form-25 publication.

For example, as of 24 of November 2020 there is following information:

````
Issuer Name.               | Symbol | Reason             | Status    | Effective Date | Form 25 Date

AMAG Pharmaceuticals, Inc. | AMAG   | Acquisition/Merger | Suspended | 11/17/2020     | 11/16/2020
```
````

Comment: If I die on November 16, the first day on which my friends will say "he is dead" is November 17.

Comment: @noob2 But Merger or Acquisition is not an accident, isn't it? If I am not mistaken, companies prepare for these events, for example file form 25 10 days before the delisting.